# Can any one help me to understand this chunk of code?

Tags: objective-c

See the chunk of code, it is a class method. Can any one give me some explanation for this method? What it has done?

```
+ (PeriodicElements *)sharedPeriodicElements {
  @synchronized(self) {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ sharedPeriodicElementsInstance = [[self alloc] init]; });
  }
  return sharedPeriodicElementsInstance;
}
```

Comment: code to make it thread safe, and use dispatch_once GCD. Search for these two terms :)

Comment: Thanks Anoop Vaidya :)

Comment: Incorrect code to make something thread safe, at that.   While incorrect, it works.   But it does raise question as to the quality of the rest of the code base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used to create a singleton. `dispatch_once` will make sure no matter how many times you call `sharedPeriodicElements`, the initializer will only be called once for the entire lifespan of your app.

The `synchronized` block is a bit overdone though because `dispatch_once` is already thread safe. Seems like you are looking at a partially mutated version of the old way of doing singletons:

```
+ (PeriodicElements *)sharedInstance {
    static PeriodicElements *sharedPeriodicElementsInstance;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedPeriodicElementsInstance == nil) {
            sharedPeriodicElementsInstance = [[PeriodicElements alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedPeriodicElementsInstance;
}
```

To be clear (thx @bbum), this is really what you should be running:

```
+(PeriodicElements *)sharedPeriodicElements {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ sharedPeriodicElementsInstance = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return sharedPeriodicElementsInstance;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am learning a sample project downloaded from iOS dev center, Thanks mprivet

Comment: To be clear, the `dispatch_once` pattern without the @synchronized is the one to use.